# How do I access data from a parent directive view?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a set of directives that handle our standard table layout for our site. For this I created two directives, one for the table and one for the columns. **The goal here is to be able to dictate the columns of the table in the parent view.**

Here's the parent view (index.html) that instantiates the directives. Note that `col-name` indicates what attribute I want to show for each row in the table.

```
<management-grid>
  <col-data col-name="name"></col-data>
</management-grid>
```

Here's the relevant aspects of the `managementGrid` directive.

```
.directive('managementGrid', function() {
  return {
    ...
    template:
      '<table>' +
        '<tbody>' +
          '<tr ng-repeat="row in collection" ng-transclude="data">' +
            '<!--The specific columns go here using col-data-->' +
          '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>' +
      '</table>',
    transclude: {
      'data': '?colData'
    },
    controller: ($scope) => {
      $scope.collection = [{'name': 'Test Row 1'},{'name': 'Test Row 2'}];
    }
  };
});
```

And the child directive which is really only used to convert to a `td` tag so the browser doesn't discard it before the directive renders.

```
.directive('colData', function() {
  return {
    ...
    scope: {
      colName: '@'
    },
    template: '<td>{{colName}}: {{row[colName]}}</td>'
  };
});
```

In the final directive `colData`, the `row` object is not accessible. I know I can use a link function to access the parent controller, but that will only allow me to access `collection` and I need to access `row`, which is created using `ng-repeat`.

Here's [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfz5v1b5/) showing the issue.

**edit:**
Ideally I could simply transclude into the `colData` directive and not have to pass a property name in. Something like `<td ng-transclude></td>` and in the parent view `<col-data>{{row.name}}</col-data>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using `$parent` in the child directive. This accesses the parent scope. [See the updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zfz5v1b5/6/).